# \b alternatives in regular expression

Tags: regex

Is there an alternative regular expression that matches \b.

I want something that matches **.** (dot) as well.

for example I want to capture **ABC.** (with . included)

I could write `\b[\w]+\b` but it doesn't capture . (dot)

I would also like to capture a word such as ***ABC*** (without dot)

So is there a way to exclude some of the characters that **\b** matches with?

Some of the stuff I like to match with same regular exppression:

```
ABC
ABC.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify the optional `.` after the `\b`:

```
\b\w+\b\.?
```

Comment: that's interesting.  I never thought of having optional **\.** after **/b**. thx mate it works

Comment: `\b` has no width; it matches the place *between* `ABC` and `.`, hence the order.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like so: `(^|\s*)\w+\.($|\s*)`.

A working solution can be viewed [here](http://regex101.com/r/oO3aE5/3).

As per your edit, this will work: `(^|\s*)([A-Za-z0-9.]+)($|\s*)`. Updated example [here](http://regex101.com/r/oO3aE5/4).

Comment: @nafas: I am checking the captured groups. Group 2, the group which contains the word does not have any spaces.

Comment: I see, so do you mean only solution is to use grouping?

Comment: @nafas: I use groups to control the `OR` operator (`|`). In this case, if the regex matches, you will need to access the second group. The other groups will contain either an empty string or white spaces.